# Bevelling a curve with object

Tags: bezier-curves

I've googled and also searched the answers here but couldn't find my problem so here goes:

I know how to bevel a curve using another object and when I try it with a normal circle it's fine. But I'm trying to use this flat oval shape to bevel a larger curve of the same shape and it's not following the curve at the correct rotation. I've tried everything, rotating the bevel object, clicking random options in the object data menu.. I can't seem to budge it from looking how it is in the screenshot. In the screenshot you can see the curve I've failed to bevel correctly and also the bevel object in the bottom right.

Basically, I want the flat part of the oval to be above and below the curve, not on the sides as it is. I hope that makes sense. Anyone know what I need to do?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to change the rotation of the bevel, you need to rotate the bevel object in *Edit mode*.

1. Enter edit mode for the small oval that is the bevel object.
2. Select all the curve points and rotate by 90 degrees (I can't tell which axis from the screenshot).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the extremely fast answer. (I'll mark it as the answer as soon as the countdown timer lets me) :)